# OpenID Connect - ID Token vs Access Token

Tags: oauth2, open-id-connect

I have setup a connected app with the "openid" scope.  Using the web server flow, my callback is able to get the Open-ID JWT from "id_token", generated by Salesforce.  My API has no problem validating this token.

The question is this:  Given this JWT, how can I use it to authorize REST calls to SF?

From my research, I cannot.  It appears I have to use it to obtain an Access Token.  I have yet to see a concrete example of this... Salesforce consuming its own Open-ID JWT in any way.  Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access token and ID token are two different animals. The former is used for authorizing API calls, the latter is used for authentication of end-user by your application/client. You cannot use an ID token to authorize calls, there's no such provision in oAuth and/or OpenID Connect spec. From the [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_web_server_flow.htm&type=5), the steps involved in Web Server flow (aka authorization code flow in OpenID Connect):

> 1. Request an Authorization Code
> 2. User Authenticates and Authorizes Access
> 3. Salesforce Grants Authorization Code
> 4. Request an Access Token
> 5. Salesforce Grants an Access Token

The OpenID Connect flavor of this is based on `response_type` being set to `code` in step 1 and having `openid` as one of the requested token scopes on the connected app. Assuming you've done this correctly, when you exchange authorization code for the access token in step 4, the response that comes back to your client in step 5 should look like this:

```js
{
"access_token": "00DB0000000TfcR!...",
"signature": "...",
"scope": "web openid",
"id_token": "..."
 ...
}
```

There are other keys that come back in this JSON structure, it's been redacted for the purposes of this answer. Value of `id_token` is the ID Token data structure in JWT format, this is the primary extension that OpenID Connect makes to OAuth 2.0 to enable authentication of end users. Value of `access_token` is the OAuth access token that can be used for authorizing API calls. You grab the value of `access_token` and make a call to any SF REST API by adding the `Authorization` header to your HTTP request in the format `Authorization: Bearer <value of access_token>`. Example with production SF API that lists resources by platform version:

```
GET /services/data/v47.0 HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer 00DB0000000TfcR!...
X-PrettyPrint: 1
```

Response (redacted for brevity):

```js
{
  "tooling" : "/services/data/v47.0/tooling",
  "metadata" : "/services/data/v47.0/metadata",
  "eclair" : "/services/data/v47.0/eclair",
  "folders" : "/services/data/v47.0/folders"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you @identigral, but I am aware of how to use an access token and how to get the open id token.  What I am asking is: How can I use the Open ID Token to accomplish anything in Salesforce?  Is there any way to use the JWT to get an Access Token?  I am wanting to take action on behalf of a Salesforce user, basically issue a Platform Event back to Salesforce, and all I have is the JWT.

Comment: Authorization / delegation of access (aka _take action on behalf of a Salesforce user_) is done with access tokens; you do have the access token at the end of authorization grant flow. Purpose of ID token from [OIDC spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html): _OpenID Connect returns the result of the Authentication performed by the Server to the Client in a secure manner so that the Client can rely on it_ . It's for your application to do stuff with.