# Validate Salesforce Access Token via custom backend app

Tags: oauth2, authentication, security-token, authorization, accesstoken

The usecase is very simple

1. I have a client app SPA in Angular(APTTUS eCommerce) using Salesforce Login for User SignIn.
2. I need to call a backend API(custom c# application) from the SPA to fetch data and show it to the user. I can pass the salesforce access token to the backend API.

QQ: How can the backend API validate the access token generated by salesforce? Is there a Key or Certificate or URL salesforce provides for me to validate the token in c# app and return data?

(Other Q: What claims does salesforce access token have vs Salesforce Identity token)

Comment: You can't validate the access token, only SF can. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/292647/openid-connect-id-token-vs-access-token for more info on two token types.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real reason to "validate" the token. If you get a 403 error when using it, the token isn't valid (and the response will tell you why). When you obtain an access token, you can parse the response to check out the [scopes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_tokens_scopes.htm&type=5). The scope tells you what you're allowed to do. Note that the scope will be the intersection of whatever you *request* and whatever you're *allowed* to do (e.g. if you request the "full" scope, but the app doesn't allow that scope, you can't have full access).

Comment: You need the Issuer Signing Key to validate the token- make sure signature is not altered with. That avoids calling a endpoint to validate the token. I am not sure why you say no real reason to validate the token?

Comment: Maybe its in https://YOUR_DOMAIN/.well-known/openid-configuration ...just need some confirmations

Comment: @Amyn You can call the Identity URL (/id/org-id/user-id) provided in the authorization response, which includes a lot of additional details as well.